# Node.js - spawn is cutting off the results

Tags: node.js, shell, child-process, spawn

I'm creating a node program to return the output of linux top command, is working fine the only issue is that the name of command is cutted, instead the full command name like `/usr/local/libexec/netdata/plugins.d/apps.plugin 1` returns `/usr/local+`

My code

```
const topparser=require("topparser")
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn
let proc=null
let startTime=0

exports.start=function(pid_limit,callback){
    startTime=new Date().getTime()
    proc = spawn('top', ['-c','-b',"-d","3"])
    console.log("started process, pid: "+proc.pid)
    let top_data=""

    proc.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log('stdout: ' + data);
    })

    proc.on('close', function (code) {
      console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
    });


}//start

exports.stop=function(){
    console.log("stoped process...")
    if(proc){proc.kill('SIGINT')}// SIGHUP -linux ,SIGINT -windows
}//stop
```

The results

```
14861 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 [kworker/1+
14864 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.02 [kworker/0+
15120 root      39  19  102488   3344   2656 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.09 /usr/bin/m+
16904 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 [kworker/0+
19031 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 [kworker/u+
21500 root      20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 [dsc] <def+
22571 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 [kworker/0+
```

Any way to fix it?
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a `top` manpage:

> In  Batch  mode, when used without an argument top will format output using the COLUMNS= and LINES=
>               environment variables, if set.  Otherwise, width will be fixed at the maximum 512 columns.  With an
>               argument,  output width can be decreased or increased (up to 512) but the number of rows is consid‐
>               ered unlimited.

Add `'-w', '512'` to the arguments.

Comment: you are right, adding this arguments solve the issue.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you work with node, you can query netdata running on localhost for this.

Example:

`http://london.my-netdata.io/api/v1/data?chart=apps.cpu&after=-1&options=ms`

For localhost netdata:
`http://localhost:19999/api/v1/data?chart=apps.cpu&after=-1&options=ms`

You can also get systemd services:

`http://london.my-netdata.io/api/v1/data?chart=services.cpu&after=-1&options=ms`

If you are not planning to update the screen per second, you can instruct netdata to return the average of a longer duration:

`http://london.my-netdata.io/api/v1/data?chart=apps.cpu&after=-5&points=1&group=average&options=ms`

The above returns the average of the last 5 seconds.

Finally, you get the latest values all the metrics netdata monitors, with this:

`http://london.my-netdata.io/api/v1/allmetrics?format=json`

For completeness, netdata can export all the metrics in BASH format for shell scripts. Check this: https://github.com/firehol/netdata/wiki/receiving-netdata-metrics-from-shell-scripts

Comment: It seems interesting, how can I integrate with my project (see code above) and send the data by socket?